# Finding a string within a variable in bash

Tags: bash

I have the following in bash:

```
string="/opt/directory/"
```

Then when I do the following:

```
if [[ $string != *"directory"* ]]
```

it interprets as if the directory is not within string. Why? How can I solve this issue?

EDIT:

I feel really silly about this, I actually had made a few changes to my script, using the forward slash one of them and I could not figured out what was wrong for about an hour and after one of you mentioned it should work like this I realised it was because somewhere in the middle I had reassigned the variable to something else, that's why it wasn't picking it up.

Perhaps I will delete this question, as it really was my fault and I don't feel it will add much to anyone!

Comment: The most difficult bugs have the simplest causes, and they often cause us to go *D'oh*!

Comment: Someone else will find this and go [D'oh!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dO37Ql91qqM) too, so just leave it in...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to work correctly. If I try this:

```
string="/opt/directory/"

if [[ $string != *"directory"* ]]; then
    echo "true"
else
    echo "false"
fi
```

Then it correctly reports `false`. In other words, the question "*does `$string` **not** contain `*"directory"*`*" is *false*, as *`$string` **does** contain `*"directory"*`*.

---

Perhaps you meant to ask "***does** `$string` contain `*"directory"*`*", in which case you have to use:

```
if [[ $string == *"directory"* ]]
```

(Note the use of `==` instead of `!=`.)

Answer (score 0):

Using:

```
string="/opt/directory/"
if [[ $string != *directory* ]]; then
    echo "not found"
else
    echo "found"
fi
```